# content changed while format XML FileContent

Tags: java, xml, java-7

I use following code to formate xml content.

```
public String xMLFileContentFormat(String fileContent) {
       try {
           DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
           DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
           InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(fileContent));
           Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
           OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(document);
           format.setLineWidth(65);
           format.setIndenting(true);
           format.setIndent(1);
           Writer out = new StringWriter();
           XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);
           serializer.serialize(document);
           return out.toString();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
           return EMPTY_SPACE;
       } catch (Exception e) {
          LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
       }
    return fileContent;

   }
```

my xml content having tag having value like this  `&lt; &gt; &amp; &quot; &apos;` but it return value like `&lt; &gt; &amp; " '`. That is last two xml special characters are converted to original symbol. But I need the same XML content as previous.

How can I get it.

Comment: what is XMLSerializer?

Comment: It is used for sequential reading of XML

Comment: I can see that, but where does it come from?